# Get rid of the name against the series which is already showing in legends

Tags: jquery, highcharts

In my line chart using Highcharts API, showing series along with lines and same name in showing in legends also.

I want like this https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/title/ but in my case series name coming above the series and legends both.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            //value: 1,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        title: {
            text: 'City<br/><span style="font-size: 9px; color: #666; font-weight: normal">(Click to hide)</span>',
            style: {
                fontStyle: 'italic'
            }
        },
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -10,
        y: 100
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Hi @Nitin Jain, Could you explain your problem more precisely? What names would you like to have in the legend?

Comment: I don't know , how to paste share and post images here,  The link I shred, if you open it, you can find lines in chart, and legends for the lines representing the name of the line.
In my case the name which is showing in legends are also coming along with each line in chart. I want ot remove it.

Comment: Nitin Jain - So you want to show only legend items without labels? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gfqp1chm/

Comment: I have used the latest js files and got expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `labelFormatter` function for a legend:

```
legend: {
    labelFormatter: function() {
        return ''
    },
    ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gfqp1chm/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormatter